# USB flash drive problem

Tags: windows, usb

I have a Windows 7 on my computer and am using Knoppix running from a CD on a another.
I copied some files from knoppix one to my flash drive and now I can't format my flash drive to use it in windows 7.

What can I do? How do I format it back to its original state so I can use it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to format it using Windows 7.

Right click on the USB key in Computer and click on “Format” to format it to NTFS or FAT32 (the last one is more compatible with different operating systems and devices, but the first one supports files larger than 4 GiB).

Or you can format your flash drive from Linux using some graphic tools like gparted or some console utils like mkfs.vfat.

Comment: I tried the first and the most logical solution but unsuccessfully. It says: The disk is write protected.

Comment: Try this: http://techsalsa.com/solution-to-remove-write-protection-from-usb-pen-drive/